# Problemas API Facebook

Tags: facebook

Criei uma aplicação com a API do Facebook para uma empresa em que trabalho. Fato é que tudo funciona perfeitamente até a parte de Logout do usuário. Todas as vezes que você desloga, acontece o seguinte erro:

```
FacebookApiException Object
(
    [result:protected] => Array
        (
            [error] => Array
                (
                    [message] => An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
                    [type] => OAuthException
                    [code] => 2500
                )

        )
```

Os scripts do facebook no meu index.php está da seguinte maneira:

```
require 'src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => 'x42xxx7191xxxxxx',
'secret' => 'xxxxbb2ce7xxxxxx472xxxx2fxf38xxx',
'cookie' => true,
));

// See if there is a user from a cookie
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
try {
// Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
echo ''.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'';
$user = null;
}
}

if ($me) {
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
```

e também o seguinte código:

```
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
        appId: 'getAppID() ?>',
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
        });
        };
        (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
        '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());
```

O código do meu logout está da seguinte maneira:

```
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
echo 'Deslogar';
```

Lembrando que ele até desloga o usuário, da um refresh na página corretamente mas antes do conteúdo da página, ele informa o erro no começo do texto.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você precisa mudar o cookie para expirar, por isso que o erro ta acontecendo. Não conheço PHP mais para o meu programa desenvolvi um algoritmo em Python que realiza o Logout. Abaixo a minha solução em Python

```
class LogoutHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        set_cookie(self.response, "fb_user", "", expires=time.time() - 86400)

    self.redirect("/")
```

Tomara que seja útil para a sua aplicação esse exemplo.